# T4MVC @Url.Action(MVC.Controller.Action()) Renders "?Area=" Parameter in QueryString

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

I am rendering a menu from a Partial Action directly to the layout, using:

```
@Html.Action(MVC.Menu.Index())
```

This action, determines which Menu partial to render. For instance, a public menu partial. Within these partials, I am also using T4MVC to render the links:

```
<ul id="navHolder">
<li class="level1">
    <ul class="mainMenu">
        <li><b>@Html.ActionLink("Welcome", MVC.Home.Index())</b>
           ...
```

For some reason, the Urls rendered by T4MVC include "?Area=" at the end:

```
 <ul id="navHolder">
    <li class="level1">
        <ul class="mainMenu">
            <li><b><a href="/home/index?Area=">Welcome</a></b>
               ...
```

I have NO areas in my project and I have turned the "IncludeAreasToken" setting to false. Oddly, this only happens if I render the partial using "@Html.Action" -- if I pull it in as "@Html.Partial" the parameter isn't rendered and the link is clean and correct. (I don't want to render it as a partial though, so please don't offer that as a suggestion ;)

Anyone out there run into this before?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something strange is going on here, and I wonder if there is some kind of MVC bug at the root. Even without using T4MVC, this happens if you write:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Welcome", "Index", "Home", new { Area = "" }, null)
```

In a regular view, this doesn't generate the bogus ?Area=, while in a Html.Action call it does. I need to ask someone on the team.

For now, you can workaround by deleting this line (around line 310) in t4mvc.tt:

```
<# if (MvcVersion >= 2) { #>result.RouteValueDictionary.Add("Area", area ?? "");<# } #>
```

Comment: I just added a check to see if the area was supplied, if so I add it to the dictionary: `if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(area)) {result.RouteValueDictionary.Add("Area", area ?? "");}`

Comment: @BradR: the problem with this change is that I think it's not always correct. When you're in an Area view and you're trying to generate a link to a top level (non-Area) view, then passing an empty area is the correct thing to do to 'escape' the current area. But with your check that won't happen.

Comment: It turns out that MVC only generates the bogus token if the app *doesn't* have any areas. So we should just fix T4MVC to only add this token if the app uses areas.

Comment: @DavidEbbo has this checking been implemented? I'm getting the same issue with the latest T4MVC

Comment: No, but there is a simpler workaround here: https://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7154

Answer (score 30):

I solve this issue in a very easy way, simply by adding to all routes that are not in area empty area route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default",
"{controller}/{action}/{i​d}",
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Comment: Just tested this and it seems like the easiest solution - just add an area of String.Empty to the default route and all the URLs generate correctly.

Comment: This doesn't work if you use attribute routing in your project. See my answer which I copid from mvccontrib archive, workitem 7154 because you cannot find it easily on the archived Codeplex site now.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from workitem 7154 comments is a solution provided by @DavidEbbo:

> A simpler workaround is to add a bogus area to your site. e.g.\n\n-
> Right click Project and choose Add / Area. Name it 'Dummy' (or
> whatever)\n- You can delete everything in there except for the
> DummyAreaRegistration.cs file

Make sure you have the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();` call in your Global.asax

This also works with attribute routing in place.