# ASP.NET MVC 3 Routes Always Have Querystring Value "Area="

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, query-string, asp.net-mvc-areas

This is an annoyance that I've experienced for a long time, but now my client is asking me to address it.

In every route that gets generated (by a non-Default route), a query string value gets appended: "`Area=`"

As an example:

```
// RouteConfig.Register():
routes.MapRoute(
    "ProfileDetails",
    "{slug}",
    new { controller = "Profile", action = "Details" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

To generate a URL to the `BadgeController.Index` action, the Default route will be applied and the result will be `/Badge`... and that's what is expected.

But to generate a URL to the `ProfileController.Details(someUser)` action, the ProfileDetails route will be applied and the result will be `/someUser?Area=` ... which will work, but the `?Area=` is unnecessary and messy.

I have no areas in my project. How do I get rid of that `Area=` query string value? This happens with all of my routes that are not the predefined Default route, not just the "ProfileDetails" one in this example.

I've tried removing the `AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas()` from my Global.asax file, since I assume it's not required.

Comment: Do you use T4MVC? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755729/t4mvc-url-actionmvc-controller-action-renders-area-parameter-in-queryst

Comment: I do... I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Wow. I searched long and hard to avoid this from happening. "Area=" (with the quotes) doesn't find that question on SO or Google.

Thanks @Brandon! If you put your reference as an answer, I can mark it.