# Why do my T4MVC generated links have "Area=" when I do not use or define areas?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC 4 and T4MVCExtension 4.0, I generate a link with `@Url.Action(T4Controllers.EnhancementList.ByVotes())` and get `http://localhost:1025/Enhancements/EnhancementList?Area=`. Any ideas on how to get rid of that extra-ugly url parameter?

**Note:** I thought of titling this "Areas? We don't need no stinkin' Areas."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly the same as [T4MVC @Url.Action(MVC.Controller.Action()) Renders "?Area=" Parameter in QueryString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755729/t4mvc-url-actionmvc-controller-action-renders-area-parameter-in-queryst). Though I thought that was fixed earlier. What T4MVC version are you using?

Comment: T4MVC 3.6.5 (according to T4MVC.tt) and T4MVCExtensions 3.0.0.0. The NuGet packages for both say 3.6.5.

Comment: The answer on the other page about adding a default `area` parameter works fine.